# Viewing whole webpage with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website but it only shows a portion of the website at the bottom it has a view more button. Is there anyway to view everything on the webpage via python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup just parses the returned HTML. It doesn't execute JavaScript, which is often used to load new content or to modify the existing webpage after it has loaded.

You'll need to execute the JavaScript, which requires more than just an HTML parser. You basically need to use a browser. There are a few Python packages to do this:

- [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)
- [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)